# How do I download document from a web page in Zend Framework

Tags: apache, zend-framework, laminas

I am using Laminas (Zend) Framework. I have created a folder for storing documents for each of the customers. Since a user can have access to public folder only, how do I make the user have access to documents stored in his/her folder? One way I could think off is creating symbolic links but I do not have
the know-how of creating dynamic symbolic links? Please advise about any other options.

Comment: Is the user authenticated? A user can access all folders on the server. Even if it 's not public. The only public folder is the public folder in the laminas root. Therefore you can store files in any folder on the server. Just access the right dir using the __DIR__ constant.

Answer (score 0):

You can serve file from controler action

```php
class FilesControler extends Laminas\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;

public function fileAction()
{
//TODO get userDir from identity
$filename= $userDir.$this->param()->fromQuery('file');
if (file_exists($filename))
        {
            $ext = substr($filename, - 3, 3);
            
            if ($ext == 'pdf')
            {
                header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
            }
            else
            {
                header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
                header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($filename) . '"');
                header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filename));
            }
            
            header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
            header('Pragma: public');
            
            readfile($filename);
        }
        else
        {
            header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
            echo "404 Not Found. $filename";
        }
        
        return $this->response;
    }
```

You can also define route like that

```php
[
   'assets' => [
      'type' => Segment::class,
      'options' => [
         'route' => '/file[/:d1][/:d2][/:d3][/:d4][/:d5][/:d6][/:d7][/:d8][/:d9]/:basename',
      'defaults' => [
      'controller' => Controller\FilesController::class,
      'action' => 'file'
      ]
   ]
]
```

and then concat filepath from route params

```php
        $directories = [];
        for ($i = 1; $i < 9; ++ $i)
        {
            $dir = $this->params('d' . $i);
            if ($dir)
                $dirs[] = $dir;
            else
                break;
        }
        $basename = $this->param('basename');
        $filename = implode('/', $dirs) . '/' . $basename;
```

URI will be more natural, but you have to limit depth of directories.

Comment: There 's no need to use the header function. Laminas handles header data inside its http response object. Just use `$this->getResponse()` inside the controller action method, to get the response object and set the header data with `$response->getHeaders()->addHeaderLine()` or at once with `$response->getHeaders()->addHeaders()`. Its recommended to use laminas functionality.